# Bing Maps API - Missing Tiles

Tags: zurb-foundation, bing-maps

Hoping someone can enlighten me on this issue I'm experiencing with the VEmap Api.

I'm embedding it in a Zurb Foundation responsive layout and it all works as expected in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox and IE it will not load the actual map tiles.

On both FF and IE the map is still loading the custom points I am adding as well as some extra layers and is plotting all points correctly. Just no base map.

When I test using percentages but outside of the Zurb framework all works fine on all browsers.

Hopefully there is an easy fix out there! Driving me bonkers!

Answer (score 0):

First off, by mentioning VEMap I assuming you are using the really old v6.3 version of Bing Maps which hasn't been updated in 5 years. It is recommended to use the newer Bing Maps v7 control which has been around for 4 years now and has seen a number of updates. It is the main map control for Bing Maps and has all the key features.

As for your issue there are a couple of things you can try. The first is to ensure you have a valid content type metadata tag for UTF8 and a valid doctype as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx. Also ensure that you have specified a CSS position, width and height value (100% is fine) for your map, otherwise it will not render correctly in all browsers.